# Having trouble with this layout, how to stretch the gradient and move the main div to the center?

Tags: html

Currently, I linked my JSfiddle below.

I have my horizontal Gradient working, stretches completely. However my vertical gradient only stretches to the bottom of the text, I really would like it to stretch to the bottom of the page. Any height code I use does not work.

Also I am attempting to make everything in the 'main' class centered. Unless I manually  the text it does not work. I tried putting height and width to auto in the CSS but id does nothing.

Could somone help me get this page aligned correctly please?

I was hoping for what is in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qcwi.jpg

Header (gradient)

Nav (gradient) | main content in the middle

footer

http://jsfiddle.net/nejhrfjz/4/

Here is my current CSS:

```
.gradient {
background-image:
linear-gradient(
 to right, 
 #276BE7 50% , #3079E7, #ffffff
);
margin:0;
display:inline-block;
width: 100%;
}

.gradientb {
background-image:
linear-gradient(
 to bottom, 
 #276BE7 , #3079E7, #ffffff
);
margin:0;
display:inline-block;
height: 100%;
}
body {
margin: 0;
background-color: #000000
}

nav {
margin:0;
}

#main {
float: left;
color: yellow;
width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the #main text, the CSS rules should look like this:

```
#main {
    color: blue;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #000000;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
```